# Mac OS X: Trouble with Local Django + PyDev install working with remote MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, pydev

I've got PyDev installed in Eclipse. I'm trying to play with Django. I'm got a remote MySQL database set up. I would really like to not install MySQL on my MacBook.

Trying to set up the MySQL plugin for python, I get

```
(djangotest)jeebus:MySQL-python-1.2.3 blah$ python setup.py clean
sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/Users/nali/djangotest/temp/MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
  File "/Users/nali/djangotest/temp/MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config
    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

The error makes sense since I don't have any of MySQL or related tools set up.

Are there an Snow Leopard MySQL libraries I can use to satisfy the need for mysql_config without actually installing MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no.  You need the *client* side libraries of MySQL but you don't need the server components.  Most package managers provide each as separate packages.

MySQL-python, AKA MySQLdb, is *not* a client module per se.  It is a wrapper or interface between Python programs and the standard MySQL client libraries. MySQLdb conforms to the [Python standard DB API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). There are other conforming adapters implemented for other database managers.  Using the common API makes it much easier to write database-independent code in Python; the adapters handle (much of) the messy differences among the various database client libraries.  Thus, you do need to install MySQL client libraries; there are several ways to do this: the easiest options are probably downloading prebuilt libraries from mysql.com or you can use a package manager, like MacPorts, to install them and other dependencies.

For OS X 10.6, because of the potential gotchas in getting all of the needed pieces installed in a compatible manner, I highly recommend using a total solution from MacPorts to get Python MySQL support.  See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272493/upgraded-python-and-cant-get-mysqldb-to-work/3272997#3272997) for more details.  MacPorts even provides a Django port.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use macports instead. It also has a gui called porticus.

Comment: I see macports has py26-mysql, but its dependency is MySQL, so that kind of defeats what I'm trying to do. Unless I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install mysql-python
```

... or use `easy_install` if you don't have `pip`.

Comment: get the same error with pip: EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

Comment: I don't know... I think I'd just go ahead and install MySql locally.  Also note, for Django dev development sqlite is generally easier to work with.